# Windows 10 Pro: My %USERPROFILE% does not match %USERNAME%

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 Pro
Home network, not joined to a domain
I am a long time user going back to Windows for Workgroups
I am a bad administrator

As I was setting up this computer, I experimented with accounts with various names, local accounts and microsoft accounts, adminstrator and restricted user.

Now CMD.EXE says

echo %username% is admin
echo %userprofile% is C:\Users\jlrub

I prefer username 'josh' and userprofile C:\Users\josh

Am I screwed, or can I recover from this?

Comment: Easiest way that does not require many hacks and stuff, create a new user called Josh, copy all your stuff over, delete the old user.

Comment: Or just leave it as is  - it will not cause any issue and is not in any way simple to change.

Comment: I second @LPChip suggestion for another reason.. otherwise, I would go with John's suggestion.  it appears that your username is "admin".. not good.

Comment: I'm living with it, but when I log into a Linux machine with SSH, the mismatch is painful and confusing.